# sum of $1/ \phi(n)^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I am reading some material on circle method. Right now
I am at its application to the binary Goldbach problem.
To obtain a certain bound the fact
$\sum_{n> X} 1/ \phi(n)^2 = O(1/X)$ 
is used. Could anyone please help me how to solve it?

Here $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.
And I would like the result without $\epsilon$.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: If I am wrong I apologize but this seems like a homework problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theorem 2.14 of "Multiplicative Number Theory" I. Classical Theory, by Montgomery & Vaughan
implies that 
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \left(\frac{n}{\phi(n)}\right)^2 = O(x)$$

Use this and partial summation method with 
$$\sum_{n\leq x}  \left(\frac{n}{\phi(n)}\right)^2 \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Or, making different assumptions of what the question means: find a function $\phi$ so that
$$
\sum_{n=X}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(n)^2} = O(1/X)\qquad\text{as } X \to \infty
$$
And in fact $\phi(n)=n$ is an example that satisfies that:
$$
\sum_{n=X}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{X}+\frac{1}{2X^2}+\frac{1}{6X^3}-\frac{1}{30X^5} + O(1/X^7)
$$

Comment: Whoever down-voted this: Gerald's answer is correct, and it is very hard to tell what the OP is actually asking, as Gerald points out.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear enough regarding my question.
It is my first time on Mathoverflow and I am still trying to
figure out how to use this properly...

Answer (score 1):

From Theorem 7 in [Pete Clark's notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400arithmeticorders.pdf) it follows that you get $O(1/X^{1-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$

Comment: A downvote? Is the answer wrong?

Comment: Two downvotes. I am honored.